# How to use a single filter over multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

In Python I want to use the same filter condition on multiple dataframes.

What I currently have is:

```
filtered_df1=df1[(df1['Timestamp'] > Lower_limit) & (df1['Timestamp'] < Upper_limit)]
filtered_df2=df2[(df2['Timestamp'] > Lower_limit) & (df2['Timestamp'] < Upper_limit)]
filtered_df3=df3[(df3['Timestamp'] > Lower_limit) & (df3['Timestamp'] < Upper_limit)]
```

In order to make the code more efficient, I have tried the following with no success:

```
Lower_limit, Upper_limit= '2019-12-4 06:00:00', '2019-12-6'

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in dfs:
    df=df[(df['Timestamp'] > Lower_limit) & (df['Timestamp'] < Upper_limit)]
```

Link to example dataframe is here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75uocnegx831d0x/AAAcp_Su-Z4ImGY-OUZsumusa?dl=0

Any suggestions would be appreciated on how to improve this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will help

```
    #convert to datetime
Lower_limit, Upper_limit= '2019-12-4 06:00:00', '2019-12-6'
Upper_limit = pd.to_datetime(Upper_limit)
Lower_limit = pd.to_datetime(Lower_limit)

#read in columns and change Timestamp to another name
#Timestamp is a type ... cant compare time with type
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv',sep=';', parse_dates = ['Timestamp']).rename(columns={"Timestamp":'timer'})
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv',sep=';', parse_dates = ['Timestamp']).rename(columns={"Timestamp":'timer'})

#run function

expression = '@Lower_limit < timer < @Upper_limit'
func = lambda x: x.query(expression)

filter1, filter2 = [func(df) for df in [df1,df2]]

#check any one
filter1.head()

    timer                 Value
13  2019-12-04 06:10:00 27.282425
14  2019-12-04 06:20:00 27.266042
15  2019-12-04 06:30:00 27.212147
16  2019-12-04 06:40:00 27.272867
17  2019-12-04 06:50:00 27.242088
```

something similar to this is described in the docs : [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#query-use-cases)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sammywemmy. 
When executing, I am getting the error message "name 'Lower_Limit ' is not defined". 
Even though they are defined: Lower_Limit, Upper Limit ='2019-12-4 06:00:00', '2019-12-6'

Comment: my bad ... prefix the variables with an ```@```

Comment: New error message: "format number 1 of "b'2019-12-4 06:00:00'" is not recognized"

Comment: do u mind sharing some rows from each dataframe, so i, and others, can test as well? data, not pics. include ur upper and lower limit as well. dat error msg looks like a binary of some sort...

Comment: The original post has been updated with the requested information.